# What is a fix for WriteFileEx not calling the completion routine?

Tags: windows, io, writefile

**Background:** I have an HID device that I'm writing to from my DLL. My DLL is loaded by DirectInput and receives data in function calls. I send some of that data to my device. Using `WriteFile`, the game bogs down likely due to the synchronous writes (it operates fine when I don't perform the write).

**Problem:** In trying to make write operations to my HID device asynchronous, I'm using the `WriteFileEx`. I'm running into an issue where my completion routine isn't being called, so I can't free the `OVERLAPPED` structure I dynamically allocate before the call to `WriteFileEX`.

**Code:**

> ```
> my_hid = CreateFile(reinterpret_cast<DIHIDFFINITINFO*>(initialization_information)->pwszDeviceInterface, 
>                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
>                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
>                    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
> ```

> ```
> LPOVERLAPPED over = new OVERLAPPED{ 0 };
> ```

> ```
> BOOL success = WriteFileEx(my_hid, effect_report, EFFECT_REPORT_SIZE, over, (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)completion_routine);
> ```

> ```
> VOID WINAPI completion_routine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
> {
>   delete lpOverlapped;
> }
> ```

**Notes:**

- The data is being sent still. Received by my HID device.
- `WriteFileEx` returns non-zero
- `GetLastError` returns zero
- No buffer allocation or deallocation is shown in the example for brevity.

Comment: Operations using the asynchronous API can sometimes still complete synchronously.  Supposed to get `ERROR_IO_PENDING` to differentiate.

Comment: Also, are you using alertable waits?  "A pointer to a completion routine to be called when the write operation has been completed **and the calling thread is in an alertable wait state**."

Comment: Also important: "f the hEvent member of the OVERLAPPED structure is NULL, the system uses the state of the hFile handle to signal when the operation has been completed. Use of file, named pipe, or communications-device handles for this purpose is discouraged. It is safer to use an event object because of the confusion that can occur when multiple simultaneous overlapped operations are performed on the same file, named pipe, or communications device. In this situation, there is no way to know which operation caused the object's state to be signaled."